# Android Studio 2.2 don't open any of projects that are created by Others

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

well I downloaded **Udacity** course exercise projects. when i tries to import an existing **Gradle** based project by selecting **setting.gradle**. Android studio opens a Window entitled with **Building project X** and progress bar and than it stucks on this screen window and nothing happens . no matter how much i wait.

**I invalidated caches and restarted the Android Studio but it wasn't handy.**

Help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just tried downloading a random project from Udacity. Here are the steps I took:

- Download project (I downloaded a zip file, which I extracted to my desktop. You can also use it if you are familiar with that).
- Open android studio

  a) If the welcome dialog appears, click Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.). Then navigate to the project folder you unzipped. Inside this folder should be folders app, gradle, and a few other files. If that is not the case you need to navigate in further. I noticed this was the case when I downloaded my project: I unzipped a folder with many mini-projects inside. You need to select a single project to import.

  b) If you open straight into an existing project you've been working on, either go to File > Close Project and then follow the steps in part a) or go to File > New > Import Project, and then navigate to your project as in part a).

This should open the project from Udacity successfully.

Comment: Thanks **Michael**